# База данных в гугл таблицах

Tags: google-spreadsheet

У меня есть 2 таблицы например таблица1-(Магазины) таблица2-(Продукты) и нужно сделать так что бы при редактировании таблицы 2 данные менялись и в первой таблице и наоборот при редактировании таблицы 2 данные менялись в первой таблице

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943?hl=ru

Comment: там нельзя редактировать данные из одной таблицы в другую